# I glued some C4 onto someone's butt, how do I get it off?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

While playing through the *Destroy the Anti-Air Emplacements* mission, I knocked out an enemy soldier patrolling near an AA cannon and decided to rig the cannon before moving the body away, so the soldier won't die from the explosion.

For some weird reason, Big Boss decided it would be wiser to attach the explosive on the enemy's... behind, instead of the cannon.

Now, I can pick up the body, put it down, or throw it; but how do I get the C4 off his butt, preferably without killing the poor (good looking) guy?

Comment: Oh as I see the out of context titles have returned. This shall be seen by everyone on SE

Comment: @Jutschge They never went away

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have looked it up and there is just no way to remove the C4 off of a body in metal gear 5, so I guess your options are to ether kill the guy or restart the campaign.